# srid doesn't change (in postgres)

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a table in `srid=4326`

I need to change the `srid` to `32636`

I tried to do this with:

```
select UpdateGeometrySRID('tbl','geo', 32636)
```

When I check the results with:

```
select st_asewkt(geo)
from tbl
```

I see that the values of `geo` are similar to `srid` of `4326` and not `32636`

I tried to change the srid with:

```
update tbl
set geo = st_transform(geo, 32636)
```

but same results

How can I transform the `geo` field from `srid 4326 to 32636` (and save it in the table)

Comment: I cannot  reproduce that.

Comment: I don't understand your comment ?

Comment: I tried it, and it works on my PostgreSQL database as you expect it to.

Comment: is there something I'm missing ?

Comment: have you set the srid first? Try select st_transform(st_setsrid(geo,4326),32636)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the alternative sql for transform of geometry, you can try

```
alter table table_name alter column geom type geometry using st_transform(st_setsrid(geom,4326),32636)
```